# Switch image with callback code with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to switch two image with .click event on the same image, with callback function on 1° image and 2° image.

my purpose is to create an simple audio player for my site with only mute/unmute function by click image.

i have **"icontrue.png"** and **"iconfalse.png"**.

The CSS on **"iconfalse.png"** is set on **"display:none"**

this is the html:

```
<img src="http://www.gastronomiasanfilippo.it/img/icontrue.png" id="true" class="show" />
<img src="http://www.gastronomiasanfilippo.it/img/iconfalse.png" id="false" class="hide"/>
```

this is the css:

```
#false{

cursor:pointer;
}
#true{
cursor:pointer;
}
.show{display:inline;}
.hide{display:none;}
```

this is jquery:

```
$("#true").click(function(){
$(this).addClass("hide");
$("#false").css("display","inline");
});
```

with this code i can't switch image ever by click event and can't have callback function, what's the way for do this?

This is jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b9ykmtLp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var muted = false;
$("#mute-unmute").click(function () {
    muted = !muted;
    if (muted) {
        $(this).addClass("muted");
        // mute(true);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("muted");
        // mute(false);
    }
});
```

```css
#mute-unmute {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/warnings-and-dangers/400/Warning-02-512.png");
    cursor: pointer;
}

#mute-unmute.muted {
    background-image: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/web-and-apps-interface/32/Cancel-512.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="mute-unmute"></div>
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/b9ykmtLp/20/

Comment: `// mute(true);` and `// mute(false);` are places where you should put your code to mute and unmute your player :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.show()` and `.hide()` and just repeat your code for the other image (`#false`).

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b9ykmtLp/16/

```
$("#true").click(function(){
   $(this).hide();
  $("#false").show();
});

$("#false").click(function(){
   $(this).hide();
  $("#true").show();
});
```

Comment: Personally I use the `background-image` approach suggested by @Bodzio because I think it is 'cleaner'.  My answer was simply easy-to-explain.

Comment: thanks i use code by @bodzio too , but ur code is nice for my other idea thanks u too :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are of course numerous different ways you can do this, but the most effective way I can think of is to use jQuery's toggle(); function - http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ this since it allows you to get rid of all unnecessary markup. At the top of my head, this is how I would do it:

Choose one of the images to be the default one and hide the other one. Then just wrap both of them in a parent div, give that div a semantic name, reference it with jquery and use toggle(); to toggle the visibility of it's content when clicked. Short and simple:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="button">
  <img src="http://www.gastronomiasanfilippo.it/img/icontrue.png" class="default" />
  <img src="http://www.gastronomiasanfilippo.it/img/iconfalse.png"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#button img {
display: none;
}

#button img.default {
display: block;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
  $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

**Here's a working fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/b9ykmtLp/13/